# What is the R function for EDA plots like this?

Tags: r, data-visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

I am searching for the R function that generated this Exploratory Data Analysis plot. Anyone know what it is?

[image]

Comment: `pairs` will do it.  Emulate the examples in its help page to generate custom density plots on the diagonal and correlation values in the upper triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot replicate your plot since you are not providing the data, but this kind of pairwise scatterplot can be done with `ggpairs` from the `GGally` package. In the diagonal, you have a nonparametric density estimate and on the off-diagonal cells, you have either the scatterplot (below the diagonal) or the Pearson correlation coefficient with the relative $p$-value shown by means of usual asterisks.

Here is the `R` code for a similar plot using the `mtcars` dataset.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")       
install.packages("GGally")
library(ggplot2)               
library(GGally)
dd<-dplyr::select(mtcars,mpg,disp,hp)
ggpairs(data)+theme_bw()
```

You can customize labels, axis, dots, etc. at will.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!